# Unit of measure for DBSCAN

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, pakistan

My code is:

```
ST_ClusterDBSCAN(st_transform(points_geom,5243),eps := 50, minPoints := 100)
```

The underlying EPSG was 4326 previously.

Am I right in assuming that the DBSCAN now is using meters as its unit of measure REGARDLESS of where I am located in the world?

I did a Google search for EPSG 5243 and it showed Germany whereas my data is for Pakistan. Would it affect my results significantly if I continue using 5243?

UPDATE:
After some research, it seems like the following code is more suitable:

```
ST_ClusterDBSCAN(st_transform(points_geom,24313),eps := 50, minPoints := 100)
```

is this more plausible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function, as well as most other analytical functions in PostGIS, apply mathematical operations based on the coordinate values of their input geometries. They know nothing about units or projections - they do math, and they don't care if they do math with a coordinate value of `0.459` (could be *degree*) or `324230984` (could be *metre*, or *foot* even).

Likewise, those functions do not care if the chosen projection is suitable for your geometric locations. And since the underlying mathematical definitions of a projection are specifically designed to suit the respective region/area of its coverage, coordinates that do not fall within that definition will be projected with varying (usually very high) levels of distortion, affecting all analytical operations and measurements.

**It is the operators responsibility to know and supply a correct coordinate reference for their data - including awareness of the underlying primary unit of reference.**

---

For Pakistan, [`EPSG.io` lists these projections](https://epsg.io/?q=Pakistan%20kind:PROJCRS&page=1), designed for different areas and with varying accuracy - you will have to find one that best covers your data.

That page summarizes each projections definition (if available, or if maintained properly), e.g.

> ##### Attributes
>
> **Unit:** metre

and provides their technical descriptions in a multitude of formats, e.g. the common `proj4` string:

> `+proj=utm +zone=43 +a=6377301.243 +rf=300.8017255 +towgs84=283,682,231,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs`

where `+units=m` specifies the primary unit of measurement.